# Linked Image Border Styles

Tags: css, image, border, visited

I want to be able to link my image. Click on it. Go back to the page and see that it was visited.
I want my visited images to have a different color border when I go back.

My code:

```
a:link img{border-color:#FFF; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;}
a:hover img{border-color:#03F; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;}
a:visited img, a:active img{border-color:#036; border-style:solid; border-width:1px;}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Link CSS can be hard to get right, because many browsers can be quirky about it. The best order to declare link CSS is

- Link
- Visited
- Hover
- Active

(Also remembered as the mnemonic LoVe/HAte).

Also, try declaring your css:

```
a:hover img {border: 1px solid #036;}
```

instead of specifying it in three different declarations.

Comment: The link/visited/hover/active order is more important than most people realize. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to tell us which browser isn't working, because they all handle anchor links that have embedded text differently.